# Problema con la renovacion de certificado Push que utiliza app mobile Genexus

Tags: genexus, certificado-apple

Hace dias que estoy intentando renovar el certificado Apple Push Notification.
De acuerdo a la documentacion https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/invalid-push-certificate hay dos caminos: uno a traves de un wizard, y otro en forma manual.

He realizado ambos métodos y obtuve el mismo resultado: me generó el archivo .CER pero al hacer dobleclick para que lo agrege al "Keychain Access" me lo muestra como certificado de No Confiaza.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si dentro del "Keychain Access" hago "Visualizar y evaluar certificados" genérica, muestra en estado de evaluación que no encontró certificado raíz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué debo hacer para que el certificado generado sea de confianza?
desde ya muchas gracias

Aca muestro otro certificado que reemplacé el mes pasado, un certificado de Distribution. Cuando abro la ventana de evaluacion se ve que automaticamente le asocio el "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations" y el "Apple Root CA"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema parece ser lo que comentas en la segunda imagen, es decir, el keychain no encuentra los root certs para el certificado que creaste.

Para estar seguro cual tenes que descargar, fijate en la segunda foto que mandaste, que certificado aparece bajo el nombre "Organisational Unit" y descarga ese.

Seguramente sea el G4, y los descargas de aca e instalas de la misma forma que instalaste el tuyo:

https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

Comment: el mes pasado en noviembre reemplace otros certificados como el de Distribution y no tuve que descargar certificados adicionales. Adjunto al detalle anterior un print de pantalla donde se que junto al certificado estan los otros dos que mencionas. Para asociarlos al certificado APN se hace desde la MAC o desde el sitio de desarrolladores de Apple ?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Descargué e instalé en la MACbook el siguiente Apple Intermediate Certificate correspondiente a la Unidad Organizativa. En este caso la G4: 
AppleWWDRCAG4.cer (Worldwide Developer Relations - G4 (Expiring 12/10/2030 00:00:00 UTC) ).
Una vez agregado al “Keychain Access”, sin mas, el otro certificado APN generado aparece como válido!